# Dynamic proxy with nginx based on url param

Tags: nginx, proxy, dynamic

I am loading images from an external site which I want to use in a 3D WebGL canvas. However this is not allowed due to origin.

The URL I am generating from the web page is as follows:

```
http://domain/somename/imagesproxy?url=http%3A%2F%2Fanothersite%2Fimage.png
```

Now I want to `proxy_pass` I assume, to the URL included in the request.

```
location /somename/imagesproxy {
     proxy_pass  ...
     proxy_set_header  host localhost;
}
```

**How do I get nginx to dynamically proxy to different URL's**

Comment: From what I have read nginx is not designed to be a forward proxy however I would like to use an nginx solution if possible.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
proxy_pass $arg_uri;
```

- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#variables

Comment: It should be `proxy_pass $arg_url;` to exactly match the argument in the question.

Comment: works great, BUT only if the "url" parameter is not urlencoded :(

Answer (score -1):

```
location = / {
    if ($args ~ "^url=(.+)") { #gets the "url" get parameter
        set $key1 $1;
        proxy_pass $key1; #use the parameter as proxy address
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer requires explanation.